# Regex to match numbers and carriage

Tags: regex, carriage-return

it is possible to match numbers and carriage together like one capturing group?
For example I want to match something like this: `0\r123456789`.
I am using this regex `(\d{10})` but it does not match a `\r`.

Edit: I want to also match first 0 before \r.

```
0\r123456789 => 0\r123456789 

0123456789 => 0123456789 

\r0123456789 => \r0123456789
```

Comment: Why don't you match `\r\d{10}`?

Comment: Why do you use {10}  ?  Do you need 10 digits specifically?

Comment: yes I need specifically 10 digits

Comment: You have 9 following digits @baby53. Are you trying to match the digits after the cariage return or in general?

Comment: In general but I want to match carriage too
I wanted something like this 
0\r123456789 => 0\r123456789  
0123456789 => 0123456789  
\r0123456789 => \r0123456789

Comment: That reads like you are interested if the string at least holds 10 digits? something like: `(?:\r*\d){10}`?

Comment: @JvdV at least 10digits + if there is a carriage, match carriage too...it is not working :( https://regex101.com/r/ylY2Bf/1

Answer (score 1):

A [carrage return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return) is matched with `\r` or `\x0D`:

```
\r\d{10}
\x0D\d{10}
```

`\d{10}` matches ten digits.

DEMO:

```js
console.log("0\r1234567890".match(/\r\d{10}/)[0].replace("\r","<CR>"));
console.log(String.raw`0\r1234567890`.match(/\\r\d{10}/)[0]);
```

Comment: Maybe I am dumb, but it is not working. https://regex101.com/r/oNJqGh/1

Comment: @baby53  You have no carriage return in that site. See https://regex101.com/r/oNJqGh/2. If you want to match a backslash followed with `r`, you need ``\\r``. Your number has only 9 digits, not 10, I added a `0` at the end. More, at regex101 com, you cannot type carriage returns, all line breaks default to line feeds, `\x0A`.

Comment: I want to match also that first 0 before \r so my number has a 10 digits

Comment: @baby53 So, what's the trouble? Add `0` before `\r`. This is the answer you need.

Comment: I dont know position of \r

Comment: @baby53 Try https://regex101.com/r/1pacz2/1, either `0?(?:\\r)?\d{10}` or `0?\r?\d{10}`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would help:
`((?:\r|\d|\n){10})`

Comment: I want to match also that first 0 before \r

Comment: @baby53 , that should match the first `0`

Comment: @baby53 , But I use a mac. So I can't do carriage returns easily